# How to break a loop when I close a figure in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, loops, matlab-figure, break

When the event of `close` is sent to a figure, I want to catch it by using the property `CloseRequestFcn` of Figure properties and want to call the function `my_closereq()`.

```
h_100 = figure(100);

for k=1:100
    % some code here
    set(h_100,'CloseRequestFcn',@my_closereq)
    pause(.2);
end


function my_closereq(src,callbackdata)
%break;
disp('closed');
end
```

I want to simply `break` the loop AND `close` the figure with the handle `h_100` ? Please advise me, how can I do?

Comment: Perhaps pass a flag to break the loop through a global variable? Also, you have to `close` or `delete` the figure yourself if you replace `CloseRequestFcn`.

Comment: nice idea of using a global variable, it may work. But how to `delete` or `close` the figure, I need its handler ... ?

Comment: @Naveh I breaked the wheel thanks to your idea of global variable, now how to close the figure ... I am digging ... :)

Comment: after you set your flag, you have to use `delete(src)` in your `my_closereq` function ... (or alternatively, use `delete(h_100)` after your loop)

Comment: that's what I did :D

Comment: this is **SOLVED** thank you guuys Naveh and Hoki

Comment: by the way, your statement `set(h_100,'CloseRequestFcn',@my_closereq)` could be outside (above) the loop, you only need to set that once ... no need to repeat it a hundred times

Comment: Okey i Will do that. Thank toi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SOLUTION

thanks to comments from : @Naveh and @Hoki

```
h_100 = figure(100);
global isCloseCalled;
isCloseCalled = false;
set(h_100,'CloseRequestFcn',@my_closereq)

for k=1:100
    % some code here
    if isCloseCalled == true
         break;
    end
    pause(.2);
end
delete(h_100);

function my_closereq(src,callbackdata)
global isCloseCalled;
isCloseCalled = true;
disp('closed');
end
```

Comment: You can "accept" your answer if nobody propose a better alternative (the green tick mark below the vote buttons). This way the question can be marked as solved and it's less work for the moderators.

Answer (score 1):

A solution without a global

```
h_100 = figure(100);
for k=1:100 
  % some code here 
  if ishandle ( h_100 ) == false
     break;
   end
  pause(.2); 
end
If ishandle ( h_100 )
  delete(h_100);
end
```

Comment: it worked and it is more simple . thank you . but `ishandle()` is not used in its place. plus, I was in need to do more things at the moment of closing. so the other solution suits me.thank you any way : upvote